# what will OS do in Windows when I use the operator new to allocate memory with the size of 1k bytes?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

It seems that memory leak occurs in my code, so I try to locate the place in my code which causes the memory leak.

In the post
[Can't obtain accurate information of available memory in the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681015/cant-obtain-accurate-information-of-available-memory-in-the-heap)
I was told that OS may allocate large memory when a small memory is request to reduce the system call.

Is it correct in Windows?

Comment: The system allocating "extra unused memory" is not related to a memory leak. It is merely overhead for a particular implementation. A memory leak is when a program does not *return* previously allocated memory when it done being used.

Comment: It could be, but whether or not that happens won't change anything to your memory leak.

Comment: OS allocating extra memory than requested is not the cause of memory leak. That is done for performance reasons. Memory leaks are caused by *your* code which does memory allocation (using `new` or `malloc`) but does not do deallocation (like `delete` or `free`).

Comment: In the previous post, is the function I　use to retrieve the available memory in the heap correct? I hope to call the function before and after one specific function to determine whether memory leak occurs in the specific function.

Comment: There are tools designed to detect memory leaks... not sure how this applies here.

Comment: I hope to detect memory leak on my own. The accurate place where memory leak is not necessary. I just hope to know whether a memory leak occurs in one function.

Answer (score 4):

What's relevant here, after seeing your other question, is not what happens when you allocate memory.  What matters is what happens when you release it.  In particular a 1 KB allocation will *never* be released back to the OS, it is too small.  It gets added to a list of free blocks, ready to be used by the next allocation of (about) the same size.

You cannot reliably detect memory leaks with VirtualQuery().

If you use Visual Studio then use its [built-in leak detection feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).  There are plenty of other tools.

Comment: who own the list of free blocks? My process or OS?

Comment: Virtual memory is owned by a process and managed by the OS.  The memory manager maintains the heap structures and implements HeapAlloc and HeapFree.

Comment: Thanks. If so, OS manages the heap of each process. Why does the function VirtualQuery() can obtain the information about the heap reliably?

Comment: There's more than one heap, a typical app uses three or more.  VirtualAlloc and VirtualQuery don't have anything to do with heaps.  You ought to check out Windows Internals to learn more about the way Windows works.

Comment: @JoggingSong, OS doesn't manage heap of a program, only it's [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Heap is managed by userspace; think of `malloc()` and `free()` you are (mostly implicitly) linking your program to.

Comment: @Griwes - malloc and free in the Microsoft CRT call HeapAlloc and HeapFree.  Those are OS functions.

Comment: @HansPassant, right, `HeapAlloc()` vs `malloc()` doesn't make that big difference. And "CRT" is "C RunTime library" - it is userspace, not kernelspace, therefore the runtime = the application manages the heap, not the OS = kernel itself. Also, I can write my own heap implementation, link it to my Windows application and never call HeapAlloc or HeapFree; OS will know nothing about my heap usage, as it will only know how much virtual memory I requested.

Answer (score 0):

On most systems (including most recent compilers on Windows), the heap manager will allocate relatively large "chunks" of memory from the OS, then divide that up into pieces for use by the program. That allocation from the OS will typically be at least tens of kilobytes.

Those large chunks of memory will be returned to the OS when the program ends execution. It *can* happen sooner than that, but end of execution is the most common.

Each of those large chunks will be tracked by the OS as a single allocation (even though the heap manager will then break it up into smaller pieces for use by your code). Any that have been released back to the OS will show up as free memory blocks.

Comment: Is there any API to query the size of large chunks allocated by the OS on Windows?

Comment: @JoggingSong: No, not that I know of.